# Check if Control is Textbox within TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, tabcontrol

To clear my text boxes I was using the following code in a form:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox || c is RichTextBox)
    {
        c.Text = "";
    }
}
```

But now my text boxes reside within a TabControl. How can I run this same type of check for text boxes, and if the control is a textbox, set the value to "". I have already tried using:

```
foreach(Control c in tabControl1.Controls)
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use this

```
foreach (TabPage t in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    foreach (Control c in t.Controls)
    { 
        if (c is TextBox || c is RichTextBox)
        {
            c.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx). `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` are the only controls that inherit from `TextBoxBase`, this is the type you're looking for:

```
var allTextControls = tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>() 
   .SelectMany(tp => tp.Controls.OfType<TextBoxBase>());
foreach (var c in allTextControls)
    c.Text = "";
```

Comment: How could I narrow this statement to only find the textboxes on the SelectedTab?  tabControl1.SelectedTab/TabPages[1] doesn't have the .Cast function.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson: `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBoxBase>()`

Comment: Thank you very much... Big help

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson: remember that `OfType` doesn't search controls recursively, so in any child control like a `Panel` that contains other controls. But the accepted answer ignores this also. Maybe desired, just keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks again!  Works like a charm... I needed to get all textboxes in a selected tab so I could validate their entries. Your solution is better than looping through all controls and checking if they are textboxes or not.

Answer (score 1):

tabControl1.Controls won't work because the tab control contains `TabPage`s. You need to target the correct page.

Alternately you can build a recursive method to do it:

```
static void RecurseClearAllTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox || control is RichTextBox)
            control.Text = String.Empty;
        else
            RecurseClearAllTextBoxes(control);
    }

    if (parent is TabControl)
    {
        foreach (TabPage tabPage in ((TabControl)parent).TabPages)
            RecurseClearAllTextBoxes(tabPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Limpiar Controles

```
        foreach (Control C in GB.Controls)
        { 
            if(C is TextBox)
            {
                (C as TextBox).Clear();
            }
            if(C is DateTimePicker)
            {
                (C as DateTimePicker).Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
            if (C is ComboBox)
            {
                (C as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
```